# Views of products just showing the first time a taxonomy term is used?

Tags: views

OK, so I have my product in Drupal Commerce basically sorted by two major taxonomies - Sport and Product Category.

What I want to do is set up a view that prints out the available product categories for a particular sport (i.e. if a product has a particular sport associated with it, then sort through that list and find what product categories are available for that sport).

I have the view somewhat figured out - but it keeps giving me repeats of the product category, where I only want a particular product category name to show up once.

For instance,  if I search for the sport 'Football'  - I get a list that looks like this:
  - Balls & Tees
  - Shirts
  - Balls & Tees
  - Balls & Tees
  - Pads
  - Shirts
  - Shoes
etc. . .

What I want is for those duplicates to be removed (so Balls & Tees only show up once).

In my current view, I have it set up to return fields of content - with the Taxonomy name of  Product Category as my only field.

I have a conditional filter of the parameter set.

I do have a relationship set of Content: Taxonomy terms on node.

I tried using aggregation DISTINCT option, but that doesn't seem to help.

I have looked through this topic -https://drupal.org/node/1200536#comment-4957410 - but I am not sure if its related or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you build your view based on nodes or on taxonomy terms? (https://drupal.org/node/770782)

I think a taxonomy terms based view is the preferred way. Maybe you already did this.

> 1) add a new view of view type "term" (not the default "node" option!)
>   by ticking the correct option after clicking 'add view'
>
> 2) add the Taxonomy Term to the list of Fields
>
> 3) Add a relationship "Taxonomy: Node" and make it obligatory
>
> 4) In the basic settings enable the 'distinct' option.
>
> 5) Add some filters to narrow the results as needed.

When setting filters you can try to use a contextual filter Term-ID with a default value set from the node page, only from the term list sports. You will also need to set a normal filter with term list product category.

Comment: Yes, as soon as I asked this question - I updated my view to check taxonomy terms instead of content, and I got the result I was looking for.   I was going to post my response, but you beat me to it!